# write persian or arabic alphabets in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new in java and I am trying to do a simple project to get familiar with that.

So, I am working on a dynamic web application which I use tomcat as server and MySQL with hibernate provider.

I want to be able to write persian or arabic alphabets in my tables. but unfortunately I cannot.

I have written this query for my database tables:

```
 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS myDb;
 CREATE DATABASE myDb CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
 USE myDb;

 drop table if exists user;
 drop table if exists resume;


create table resume(
    resumeId INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    resumeDescription NVARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (resumeId)
) charset = utf8; 

create table user(
    userId INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    resumeId INTEGER UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (userId),
    FOREIGN KEY (resumeId) REFERENCES resume(resumeId)
) charset = utf8;
```

I have tried to insert persian alphabets. I have created a form and made a servlet for that to handle the request. I've got parameters from the request and tested them. At that moment they were ok and they were shown properly. but when I insert them in database I face with this:

(the question marks are persian alphabets)

[image]

I dont know what to do and what is the problem.
I have searched for this problem on the internet and tested different ways but none of them worked in my case.

Can anyone please help me to write  persian alphabets properly in mySql database?

by the way my connection url is this:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`

Comment: Can you please confirm where the error is happening? The '?' could represent data that was incorrectly written to the database, or it could simply be that the program displaying the '?' isn't configured for the Persian alphabet. (I would try manually inserting a Persian character in the database and seeing how that displays)

Comment: @HeavyE thanks for your answer. but I couldn't get exactly what you mean. can you explain more?

Comment: In the question, you provided an image of the database data with a bunch of '?'s. Is it possible that the tool you are using to view the database doesn't handle the Persian characters? I would try running 'INSERT INTO RESUME(resumeDescription) VALUEs ("جیم");' manually on the database. If you still have '?' displayed, then your tool for viewing the database is the problem. If, however, the character displays correctly, then we have isolated the problem to Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following connection url:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

This will force the driver to use UTF-8.

Comment: this will cause error in building the project: `The reference to entity "useUnicode" must end with the ';' delimiter.`

Comment: By the way, I tried the solution which this error says, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Could you please try modifying your query for database modification?
`DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS myDb;
 CREATE DATABASE myDb CHARACTER SET 'utf8';`

Comment: @TTS This is marked as the accepted solution, but the comments indicate that it doesn't work. Did this solve the problem? (If it did, then should the comments be deleted?)